# Count how many rows have the value 1 in all given columns?

Tags: postgresql, query

Table `task1` has these columns:

```
workspace_id
user_id
scheduling_user
expenses_used
time_off_used
```

Each workspace (`workspace_id`) has one or more users (`user_id`).

`scheduling_user`, `expenses_used`, `time_off_used` show if users used that feature (1), or not (0).
This solution is correct, but there must be an easier way?

```
select count(workspace_id)
from task1
where scheduling_used= 1
and expenses_used = 1
and time_off_used = 1
```

Comment: Thats easy enough.  Is there a problem with it such as speed or incorrect result.

Comment: Everything is fine, Im just wondering if there is a different way, because what if I'm working with lets say 20  columns, so I thought there must be some better solution.:)

Comment: There are other ways of doing it, but for speed of reading, this is probably the best.  How many rows are you expecting, say over 5 years ?

Comment: Name the *one* RDBMS you are working with. Solutions are typically different for different RDBMS.

Comment: Did you mean how many **rows** have the value 1 in all columns?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yess, exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres you could use the [`= ALL ()` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.17):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   task1
WHERE  1 = ALL (ARRAY[scheduling_used, expenses_used, time_off_used]);
```

But obfuscating predicates this way will disable the use of indexes on individual columns.
Really only shortens the code for *many* columns.

Comment: Understood, it works, thanks and how does ARRAY work in here?

Comment: @Al_Milly That's the [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS). You must either provide an array or a set.